# MCBL Controller through RS232

Tags: serial, communication

I'm trying to use the [MCBL Controller](http://www.micromo.com/manuals/sites/en/steuerungen/mcbl_3006_s_rs.html) by Faulhaber to control my motor. I'm trying to program some sort of driver on linux using the serial connection and libserial. But it does not seem to be working for now.

I'm using the usb to RS232 converter like this one:

[image: Cable]

I'm wondering if it's well supported by libserial. I've read that yes but does anyone have any experience with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself.

Yes it works flawlessly, you just need to take care of the different parameters for the connection. Especially the flow control one needed to be set at none.

Then just send the command using a std::string and the "<<" operator.